# How to install BSD ethernet driver in Linux?

Tags: drivers, ethernet, bsd

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an old Dell Dimension 4600 that's like 15 years old. I got it for free and it came with an ethernet card that isn't working with the e100 module that arrived with Ubuntu by default.

Card is *Intel Corporation 82562EZ 10/100 Ethernet Controller (rev 02)*

Another user pointed me to [this page for the fxp ethernet driver](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man4/if_fxp.4freebsd.html) that covers various Intel ethernet adapters, that includes these installation instructions:

> To compile this driver into the kernel, place the following lines in
>   your kernel configuration file:
>
> ```
>        device miibus
>        device fxp
> ```
>
> Alternatively, to load the driver as a module at boot time, place
>   the   following line in loader.conf(5):
>
> ```
>        if_fxp_load="YES"
> ```

First, it is my understanding that BSD's kernel config file is different than Linux's Kconfig file, so I am not sure about adding those lines to the `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/Kconfig` file that I have.

As for the second option suggested,

```
$sudo modprobe fxp
```

returns

```
#FATAL: Module fxp not found.
```

**So I think I need to do something with the `if_fxp.4freebsd` file that I downloaded from that Ubuntu Manuals page before I can load the fxp module, but I don't know what.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a problem that is not related to the driver. I didn't have a router in my network, only a modem. So my ISP was probably limiting my IP addresses (not giving my Dell one). I am going to look into getting a router.